# The primes have cardinality $\aleph_0$. How does their powerset also have cardinality $\aleph_0$?

Tags: infinity

Given that the cardinality of the naturals is the smallest infinite cardinal ( $|\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$ ), and the primes $\mathbb{P}$ are an infinite subset of the naturals $\mathbb{N}$, we know that that:

$$|\mathbb{P}| = |\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$$

However, Cantor's theorem states that for any set $A$ where $|A|=n$, its powerset has a greater cardinality; i.e., $|\mathcal{P}(A)| > n$.
There is a simple injection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{P})$ to $\mathbb{N}$: just multiply each set of primes together to get a unique natural (sorry, I'm not sure how to notate this). Therefore, it would seem that:

$$|\mathbb{P}| < |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{P})|\le|\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: *Hint*: Where does your "injection" send $\mathbb{P}$? $\mathbb{P}-\{2\}$?

Comment: To make the hint even more explicit: you're forgetting about infinite sets.

Comment: If the subset of $\mathbb P$ is infinite , you cannot multiply the primes in this subset together to get a natural number.

Comment: What you have shown there is that the set of _finite_ subsets of $\Bbb P$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$.